# Autodesk forge download thumbnail in react app

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I would like to fetch the thumbnail of model and display in my react web application.
Using axios, I'm able to get CDN URL using api: `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/<MODELURN>/manifest/<IMAGE_DERIVATIVE_URN>/signedcookie`
But in response headers, I don't see 3 'Set-Cookies' which are required to get image data. On the other hand, if I try same from PostMan, I could see 'Set-Cookies' in response headers.
Can someone please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Model Derivative service provides an endpoint specifically for thumbnails: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/thumbnails/urn-thumbnail-GET. If you use that one, you won't have to worry about the S3 access workflow.

Comment: Thank you @Petr Broz. This helped. I did set 'responseType' to 'blob' and from response 'const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);'